# Указатели, delete и nullptr

Tags: c++, указатели, память, delete

Сап! Объясните максимально подробно, пожалуйста, что именно делают delete и nullptr для указателей. 
Вот код:

`````
````c++
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 int a = 5;
 int *ptr = &a;
 int *ptr_ptr = ptr;
 cout << *ptr << endl;
 cout << *ptr_ptr << endl << endl;
 delete ptr; // 1 случай
 cout << *ptr_ptr << endl;
 cout << *ptr << endl << endl;
 ptr = nullptr; // 2 случай
 cout << *ptr_ptr << endl;
 cout << *ptr << endl;
}
`````

Собственно, вопросы:

1) Почему в случае 1 выводится 5, хотя указатель ptr был удалён?

2) Почему в случае 2 не выводится 5 и программа крашится при попытке вывести ptr?

3) Почему в случае 2 вывод ptr_ptr происходит успешно, не смотря на то, что этот указатель ссылается на ptr, при попытке вывести который программа крашится?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Удален - это значит, что это место помечено как свободное для другого использования, но не затерто (эта пятерка продолжает там лежать), и сама переменная, в которой хранится адрес, не изменяет своего значения. Вот вы и обращаетесь к памяти, в которой лежит ваша пятерка, но которую запросто могут переписать...

Только то, что вы делаете - *НЕВЕРНО!*: нельзя удалять память, не выделенную через `new`! Вот если бы у вас было

```
int * ptr = new int(5);
```

тогда писать `delete ptr` было бы можно...

А в случае 2 вы меняете значение, хранящееся в переменной, и оно не указывает никуда (т.е. такое значение - `nullptr` - не может быть корректным адресом чего угодно). А в `ptr_ptr` осталось старое значение указателя - указывающее на ту самую пятерку (а не на `ptr`, как вы пишете).

И вообще - запомните одно правило - освободили память - все, забудьте о ней. А если что и работает - так ведь и не каждого пешехода, перебегающего дорогу на красный свет, сбивают... Но это не значит, что его не собьют в следующий раз.

Попробую аналогию. Дома на улице - память, конверт с адресом - указатель.

```
int * p = new int(5);
```

Подписан договор аренды, в конверт `p` вложена бумажка с адресом дома, в дом въехала пятерка.

```
int *p_p = p;
```

В конверт `p_p` вложена копия бумажки из конверта `p`.

```
cout << *p << endl;
```

`cout` смотрит в конверт `p`, идет в дом, адрес которого там указан, смотрит, кто там живет, выводит...

```
delete p; // 1 случай
```

Договор аренды разорван, но пятерка никуда не выехала. В конверте `p` так и продолжает лежать адрес дома - только эта бумажка ничего не стоит: в любой момент дом может быть сдан в аренду кому-то другому и новый жилец просто выставит старого...

```
cout << *p_p << endl;
```

`cout` смотрит в конверт `p_p`, там лежит копия бумажки, которая никуда не делась. Идет в дом, адрес которого там указан, смотрит, кто там живет, выводит...

```
p = nullptr; // 2 случай
```

Из конверта `p` выбрасывают бумажку (заменяют ее чистой бумажкой без адреса).

```
cout << *p_p << endl;
```

В конверте `p_p` так и лежит бумажка со старым адресом - ее же никто не трогал... `cout` смотрит в конверт `p_p`, идет в дом, адрес которого там указан, смотрит, кто там живет, выводит...

```
cout << *p << endl;
```

`cout` смотрит в конверт `p`, обнаруживает там пустую бумажку и не знает, что делать...

Comment: Хорошо, в случае описанном вами даже после delete ptr все ещё работает ptr_ptr, тоесть чтобы удалить эту динамическую переменную нужно удалить и ptr, и ptr_ptr?

Comment: Смотрите объяснение для малышей далее в ответе...